# As long as there is a break statement (in any scope) within a while loop- when this is reached does the while loop terminate?

Tags: python, while-loop

I have the following while loop:

```
while pointer < len(stack):
    temp_string +=1
    if stack[pointer] == "[":
        break

    pointer +=1
```

Now, I know that  the break statement will cause the `while loop` to terminate, but am I right to say that as long as there is a `break` statement within the `while loop` (in any scope), as soon as it is reached, we break out of the while loop? i.e:

```
while pointer < len(stack):
    temp_string +=1
    if stack[pointer] == "[":
        if ....: 
            if ...: 
                break
    
    pointer +=1
```

So for the above, once we hit the break, it will break out of the while loop? Is this correct? And does the same apply to while loops within while loops?

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: It breaks out of the inner most loop you are in

Comment: Also, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: Where are the scopes? Are you talking about the if-statements? Cause they don't create scope; [Python doesn't have block-scoping](/a/6167952/4518341).

Comment: Ohh thanks wjandrea- I assumed that each 4 spaces is a new scope. But now I understand this is not necessarily the case!

Comment: "Scope" is usually reserved to talk about the namespace in which a variable name is defined, although one could overload the term to refer to the loop which a particular `break` statement applies to. `if` is not a loop, so it's not relevant.

Comment: I see! This makes so much more sense now. Thanks chepner the explanation helps a lot